# Check if INSERT succeeds

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here I am trying to insert the values in the table course_student.The query is running successfully but after inserting values in the database I am not getting any alert.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$connect =new mysqli("localhost","root","","new");
if(!$connect)
{
    die("Database connection Error".mysql_error());
}

//select database

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Database selection Error".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$course=$_POST['select1'];
$userid=$_SESSION['user_id'];

$sql="INSERT INTO course_student (Courseid,Studentid)VALUES ($_POST[select1],'$userid')";
$result=$connect->query($sql);  
if ($result)
{  ?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
alert("fail");
</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<script>
alert("fail");
</script>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, what are you getting? Anything? An error? Fudge?

Comment: Have you tried checking mysql_error() - or it's mysqli* alternative?

Comment: To keep it simple, remove the JS alerts and add simple echo statements.

Comment: Also someone point him that his code is prone to sql injection

Comment: I sure hope Little Bobby Tables doesn't enroll in that course.[http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL code, read up on [proper escaping practices](http://bobby-tables.com/php) before you create even more [gigantic SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `$_POST` data **never**, **ever** goes directly in a query string. There are no excuses for this.

Answer (score 0):

1st - you can do `echo "<script>alert('something')</script>";` it a lot clearer than what you have, 2nd - `echo $result;` and check it's result.

Answer (score -2):

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO course_student (Courseid,Studentid)VALUES ('".$_POST[select1]."','$userid')";
  $check = mysql_query($sql);
  if($check)
  {
  //If succeed
  }
```

Comment: Any answer with `$_POST` in the query string is an automatic **NO**.